# Set the depth of image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

How can I set the depth of an image to **1 Byte**? I import an image with the help of the Matlab Imaging toolbox the following way:

```
UT = imread('ut.jpg');
```

Comment: Is UT a color or a grayscale image? When converting depth to 1 Byte, do you still need a color palette or just 256 shades of gray?

Comment: or just 50? i'm sorry, i had to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal RGB images (bitmap, png, etc.) are structured as a matrix with `M x N x 3 uint8` entries. Each layer respresents the intensity of one of the main colours (red, blue green). Note, that `uint8` has the same meaning as `byte`. `u` (unsigned) means it just looks at positive numbers and `8` is the amount of bits that the numbers occupy, which is `0 to 255`, `0` being black and `255` white.

In order to convert your image into a single matrix with `uint8` (or `byte`, the same) you have to perform a grey conversion:

```
UT = imread('ut.jpg');
greyImg = rgb2gray(UT); % conversion to uint8
```

For more information on how the conversion is calculated and how the weights are distributed between each colour, check out the [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html).